# Declared models are not getting applied in my existing database in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Model named `User` in my models.py file also I have incoprorated a follow feature in my Flask App but then when I add followers table in my models.py file, the same is not getting reflected or applied in my site.db file where the database is stored. I get an error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: followers`

Here is my models.py file

```
followers = db.Table('followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    followed = db.relationship(
        'User', secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

I used the commands `flask db -migrate` and `flask db upgrade` too but then it still throws that error.

How do I apply those changes in my database?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to initialize/create the tables first for `followers`. Please read the [*Creating the Database* article in the official Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/dbinit/):

> Such systems need a schema that tells them how to store that information. So before starting the server for the first time it’s important to create that schema.

Here's Flask's example of using a schema SQL script to create the database, tables, etc:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql
```